# magento 2 create table (setting) in the system configuration save or delete values in custom table

Tags: magento-2.1

I have create a  custom table with insert/delete table in system configuration. 
On click save configuration it save value in "core_config_data" table. For that I have referenced http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-backend-guide-to-create-table-setting-in-the-system-configuration link

I want in configuration table field it will display my custom table's record and on click delete button It will delete record from custom table.